# How do I use CLR Profiler to debug an ASP.Net app running on IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks, clrprofiler

I am having memory leak issues with my ASP.Net application. I've tried WinDbg, which IMO displays mostly useless information, and I'm currently trying to get the CLR profiler to work.

**My problem is everytime I try to "Profile ASP.NET" It just flashes two consoles up so fast I can't read them, then the title bar of the CLR Profiler says "Starting IIS. Error 2 occurred."**

- IIS 7.5
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Other things to know:

I did try running the CLR Profiler as administrator.

I really need to identify the source of my memory leak, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I've already seen this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

Comment: Not a real answer hence the comment. I have no experience with CLR profiler but had great results with ants memory profiler http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm (free trial available)

Comment: Good idea, just tried it, it worked well on my local, unfortunately, it didn't work at all on my production machine, which is what I need.

Comment: Hey, any luck yet? I have the same issue with CLR Profiler...

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same issue. I stoped IIS explicitly myself. Than I was able

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here, the above post helped - I resolved it by running CLRProfiler as 'Administrator'

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem when using an old, incorrect version of the CLR Profiler (not for use with .NET 4). Make sure you're using the right version of the CLR Profiler for the .net environment you're in:

- [CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273)
- [CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13382)